# What is a LAU2 level admin boundary shapefile available via a persistent URL (for reproducible research)?

Tags: r, geospatial

I'm writing up some research in .Rmd and am trying to set this up as reproducible research, that is [in a form](http://kbroman.org/knitr_knutshell/pages/reproducible.html) which can be executed and recompiled by other users. Towards this end, I'm looking for a shapefile with LAU2 level administrative boundaries (i.e. local parishes) that can be downloaded directly to R (using something, as shown below such as getURL) via a persistent URL (ideally from a reliable repository), something like what I've done for my own POI data:

```
ecs <- read.csv(text=getURL("http://datashare.is.ed.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/10283/1943/ECS-GIS-Locations_2.9_simplified.csv"))
```

The [OS BoundaryLine](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/boundary-line.html) data would be great, except that it sits behind a request form that has to be filled out and then a download URL is provided via email. GADM and Natural Earth are terrific resources, but AFAIK don't provide parish or county-level boundaries. Can anyone recommend an alternative, but nonetheless canonical / reliable alternative?

Comment: Perhaps this question over on GIS is of use? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/495/free-administrative-boundaries-available-as-shapefiles-for-united-kingdom-new-z

Comment: Thanks Les - should have mentioned this in the original question. GADM and Natural Earth only support country-level boundaries with varying degrees of precision. I may post a similar question over at GIS though and see if the R folks over there have an idea for this.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but I had a quick click through your original link to the license - http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/doc/open-government-licence/version/3/ You are free to publish the data as long as you attribute the source. Perhaps you can host the file yourself and put attribution in your code? Usual caveats apply, I'm not a license expert etc etc :)

Comment: Yeah, I've actually been thinking along those lines this morning. Seems like it wouldn't be hard to repackage some of the standard canonical shapefiles and set them up in a repository myself provided licenses match and reuse isn't prohibited. Further, it seems like maps() is just waiting for a few more data sets - it's a bit miserable with just a bunch of USA maps at the moment...